# Upload file to a server just by relative path /assets/image/img.png - By JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic app, I've some images in the assets directory. I'm trying to send one of each by getting its path and casting to a File object as you can see in my post and sending it to a server.
Here how I can implement in this way

```
const img = "/assets/img/E88MIfBTVCjmB10U1GLF_elderlies.jpg";

var imgage = new File(["foo"], img, {
  type: "image/jpg"
});


var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file", image);    
return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, formData, {
  headers: headers
});
```

Comment: relative path to what? I'm assuming client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
  async uploadFile() {
    const img = "/assets/img/iKtafmNpSGyj57ZRckVt_earing.jpg";
    this.convertRelativeUriToFile(img, 'a',null, (file) => {
      console.log(file)
      this.uploadCare.uploadImage(file).subscribe(console.log, console.log);
    })

  }
  async convertRelativeUriToFile (filePath, fileName, mimeType, cb) {
    mimeType = mimeType || `image/${filePath.split('.')[filePath.split('.').length - 1]}`;
    const imageUrl = await fetch(filePath);
    const buffer = await imageUrl.arrayBuffer();
    cb(new File([buffer], fileName, {type:mimeType}));
  }
```